# removing the div appended using append method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

this is my code...append is working but removing is not working. how to remove the appended div?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function view(){
        $('body').append('<div class="added"><p>something</p></div>');
      };
      function close(){
        $('.added').remove();
      } ;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a onclick="view();">something</a>
    <a onclick="close();">close</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i wrote diff code by mistake..this is my code right now..which is not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify `window.close` in your html handler:

```
   <a onclick="window.close();">close<a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZTwd7/1/

Otherwise `close()` refers to the native `close` method, which doesn't do anything.

Here's how you would emulate it with a "javascript" (as opposed to inline html attribute) handler:

```
elem.onclick = function(event) {
    with(Window.prototype) {
        with(document) {
            with(this) {
                close();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This is not exact reproduction (nor does it work in IE etc, that's not the point) but it would put the `.close` in `Window.prototype` in front of the global `window.close` in the scope, so it shadows it. You can still refer to it explicitly with `window.close()`.

---

You should also totally drop the above and use jQuery instead:

```
<a id="view">something<a>
<a id="close">close<a>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#view").click(function() {
        $('body').append('<div class="added"><p>something</p></div>');

    });
    $("#close").click(function() {
        $('.added').remove();

    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZTwd7/5/

---

Making an ajax request that fetches a html file to be appended:

```
$.get("myhtml.html", function(html) {
    $("body").append(html);
}, "html");
```

Comment: Well he is doing that inside his function... - Sorry, just read your comment, didn't know he changed his code.

Comment: that is working but can you explain..how just adding 'window' making it work fine?

Comment: @user1531746 because `window.close` is shadowed by `Window.prototype.close`. Another reason to avoid html handlers, they have a lot of `with` magic.

Comment: @user1531746 here's an example of what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/6SBfh/. The code inside html events implicitly runs with heightened scope.

Comment: can we append whole html file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with that?

Comment: i mean as i am now writing what div i want to append '.append(div we want to add)'...so here instead we can write those divs in seperate html file and give that name in append function...will that work?

Comment: @user1531746 you can make ajax request to the html file and then append the result in the response callback. But it requires different code... I can make an example

Comment: @user1531746 I have made the example now.

Comment: @user1531746 yeah that will work if you have pointed to the right address and `zoom.htm` exists.

Comment: @user1531746 what is the address of your file? `http://www.mysite.com/zoom.htm` ? If that works when you visit the page in the browser, it will also work with ajax.

Comment: @Esailija he broke ajax?! What on earth will we do with out asynchronous XML and HTTP requests now?!

Comment: @user1531746 Use the same address that works in browser address bar. For example, `"http://www.mysite.com/zoom.htm"` If that works in browser address bar, it WILL work in `$.get`, provided you do it right.

Comment: **Holy Derailed question batman?!** *I think it is time to accept this answer, and if you have an issue with $.get() open a relevant question and not 18 comment discussion*

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why but by putting another name to close function instead of close() it works

```
<html>
    <head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
            function view(){
                     $('body').append('<div class="added"><p>something</p></div>');
            };
            function close_it(){
                                       $('.added').remove();

            } ;

    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <a onclick="view();">something<a>
   <a onclick="close_it();">close<a>
</body></html>
```